# Laravel 5.X. make:mail not working

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a mailable object using the steps described in a tutorial, iWhenI used the command

> php artian make:mail

It is saying make:mail is not defined. Please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: which version you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail), the `make:mail` command is available only in Laravel 5.3 and higher.